# LESS CSS Dynamic Class Name

Tags: css, class, dynamic, less

I am writing this LESS file and I kind of stuck.

The code is as follows:

```
.flag (@code) {
    (~'.@{code}') {
        + label {
            &:after {
                background-image: url('images/flags/@{code}.png');
            }
        }
    }
}

input[type='radio'] {
    &.flag {
        .flag(us);
    }
}
```

Right now, this produces the following CSS (note the space between .flag and .us)

```
input[type='radio'].flag .us + label:after {
    background-image: url('images/flags/us.png');
}
```

However, the result that I am looking for should be as following:

```
input[type='radio'].flag.us + label:after {
    background-image: url('images/flags/us.png');
}
```

Obviously I need the combinator (&) somewhere. But I can't seem to figure out where exactly. Everything I have tried so far results either in parsing errors or undesired results. Is it even possible to begin with?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 7):

**[** Late answer, but better to have one here **]**

As of **LESS 1.3.1** (Oct 2012) you can use `.@{classname}` instead of `(~"@{classname}")` to dynamically generate class names, which then allows for the use of `&` before the class and this code

in **LESS:**

```
.flag (@code) {
   &.@{code} {
        + label {
            &:after {
                background-image: url('images/flags/@{code}.png');
            }
        }
    }
}
input[type='radio'] {
    &.flag {
        .flag(us);
    }
}
```

will produce the desired **CSS:**

```
input[type='radio'].flag.us + label:after {
  background-image: url('images/flags/us.png');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

there is a feature request to allow & in the escaped selector or cope with this case, but I don't think there is a work around for now. if you find one I'd like to know.